# Panasonic MSMO22F2G (stepper motor hook-up)

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor

I have a Panasonic MSMO22F2G Servo Motor that I'm using as a stepper motor. The motor has 4 wires coming out of a port farther to the front, and 11 wires coming out of a port towards the rear of the unit (presumed to be the encoder). I am trying to drive the motor with an arduino motor shield.

My question is this, how do i hook it up?

I have read that a stepper with 4 leads is a bipolar stepper, and that you group same coil wires together. I found that 3 wires on my stepper were on the same coil and the fourth seems to have no effect on the stepper. My checking process was using an ohm meter to see what was connected to what, as well as connecting wires and feeling the resistance.

Comment: Cross post: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/208627/25328